# Nutch 1.8 and Apache Solr 4.8 integration job fail

Tags: apache, solr, nutch

I am trying to crawl the web using Nutch 1.8 and Solr 4.8 on Windows 7.

```
bin/crawl urls newsolr http://localhost:8983/solr/ 1 -depth 1
```

I keep getting the following error

```
Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1252)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:114)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:186)
```

Here is the part of the log file:

```
2014-07-01 16:58:33,613 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: content dest: content
2014-07-01 16:58:33,613 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: title dest: title
2014-07-01 16:58:33,613 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: host dest: host
2014-07-01 16:58:33,613 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: segment dest: segment
2014-07-01 16:58:33,613 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: boost dest: boost
2014-07-01 16:58:33,613 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: digest dest: digest
2014-07-01 16:58:33,613 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: tstamp dest: tstamp
2014-07-01 16:58:33,613 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: id
2014-07-01 16:58:33,613 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: url
2014-07-01 16:58:33,643 INFO  solr.SolrIndexWriter - Indexing 1 documents
2014-07-01 16:58:33,773 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0001
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Method Not Allowed

Method Not Allowed

request: http://localhost:8983/solr/
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:430)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.solr.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:155)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.close(IndexWriters.java:118)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:216)
2014-07-01 16:58:34,628 ERROR indexer.IndexingJob - Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1252)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:114)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:186)
```

Finally, Solr's error log:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=http://.com/] unknown field 'tstamp' `
```

This is my first solr/nutch setup.

Comment: please say what you're doing exactly, what you have done so far in the setup of the whole thing and what you've tried to solve the problem

Comment: I am trying to crawl a website using Nutch and load it into Solr.  I have installed Nutch 1.8 using Cygwyin, and Solr 4.8 using the Heliosearch distribution on Windows 7.  Nutch and Solr work properly, but when I run a crawl using Nutch including the Solr instance (localhost:8983) then I get the error noted above.  Copying the Nutch schema-solr4.xml file into Solr didn't work.  I also researched the unknown field 'tstamp' error and tried modifying the field in the schema.xml to <field name="tstamp" type="*date*" indexed="false" stored="true"/>.

Comment: instead of the original <field name="tstamp" type="date" indexed="false" stored="true"/>, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Do Solr generate any other errors when starting up? The error message indicates that the field is missing from the schema, so do you see the field in the Admin interface?

Answer (score 0):

Just stop the solr instance and start it again. It should solve your problem.
The error occurred because you made changes to the schema file and didn't restart solr in order for the changes to be saved hence solr is unable to "see" the newly added fields.